# Symfony's Custom entity validation does not work in Behat

Tags: validation, symfony

Can anyone please tell me how can i force this custom validation while creating new data in FeatureContext?

I want `Outcome` to be created only if it has valid phase which can be accessed by Outcome::getAllowedPhases(). It works well if i create new Outcome using API becuase it successfully loads this following custom validation:

## validation.yml

```
Temando\Component\ShippingOption\Model\ConditionCartContentsTotalValue:
properties:
    operator:
        - Choice: { callback: getAllowedOperators, message: '{{ value }} is not a valid `operator`' }
```

But does not give me any error if i create it in Context and persist it `$manager->persist($outcome)`.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Please ignore above sample code. Following is relevant:

```
\Model\Outcome:
properties:
    phase:
        - Choice: { callback: getAllowedPhases, message: '{{ value }} is not a valid `phase`' }
```